# Can I covary exogenous and endogenous latent variables in SEM in lavaan

Tags: residuals, covariance, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, lavaan

*I am editing the question as it was too meandering.* I am sorry about that.

I am running an extended Theory of planned behavior (TPB) model of digital piracy and I have a question that boils down to - **is it allowed to correlate latent exogenous and latent endogenous variables (therefore their residual) in SEM using lavaan?**

The original TPB model looks like this but without the variable - behavior.  [image: Text]

The extended model that I am testing looks like this but without the SOFTWARE COST variable and the CERTAINTY-PBC relation.

[image: Text]

```
model4<- 
'ATT  =~ att1 + att2 + att3 + att4 + att6 + att7
SN =~ sn1 + sn2 + sn3r + sn5r
PBC =~ pbc1 + pbc2 + pbc4 + pbc5
INT =~ int1 + int3 + int4 + int5

CERTAINTY =~ cert3 + cert4 + cert2
SEVERITY =~ ps2 + ps3 + ps1r

INT ~ ATT + SN + PBC
ATT ~ CERTAINTY + SEVERITY

ATT ~~ PBC + SN
PBC ~~ SN'
```

A small number of papers that use an extendend TPB model in the context of digital piracy, and that explicitly graph/model covariances between ATT and SN and PBC, all have other exogenous variables that are regressed on ATT and SN and PBC. Therefore when they model their covariance they get a residual covariance relation as they are all endogenous.

Given that, **in my model, I only regress exogenous variables on ATTITUDE and that SN and PBC are still exogenous**, I am wondering  **is it allowed to add a covariance relation between ATT and SN + PBC?** I understand that I am then basically covarying the residual part of the ATT with SN and PBC as is shown in the output `.ATT~~SN`; `.ATT~~PBC`.

I am gratefull your time and answers.

Comment: A small point of terminology clarification: the correct phrasing is always “dependent variables are regressed onto predictor variables.”